# Restore purchase swift 4 programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, restore

This problem occurs to me: Purchase a subscription through a movie with a lock. I click on the camera button. The subscription view opens. I make my purchase: I display an error message (but the purchase is still successful).

```
func subscribe(sub: SubscriptionType) {
DispatchQueue.main.async { let _ = MBProgressHUD.standardHud(over: self.managedView) }
FS2Recipes.subscribe(sku: sub.sku()).then { _ in
    self.subscribed()
}.catch { error in
    debugPrint("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ooops", message: "There was an error processing your purchase. Try again later!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.dismiss()
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}.always {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { let _ = MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.managedView, animated: true) }
}
```

}

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSSMJ.jpg)

Comment: What's the error? BTW - just print `error`, not `error.localizedDescription`.

Comment: the error lies in the fact that even if it comes out that the purchase was not successful, in reality it was successful and the purchases are discharged.